# PushbackInputStream and mark/reset

Tags: java, stream, reset, push-back

I use [`PushbackInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PushbackInputStream.html) to look ahead the next byte in a stream (`bufferedIn` which is a `BufferedInputStream`) because I want to `mark()` **before** some value, and later to rewind **prior** to it using `reset()`.

```
// Wrap input stream into a push back stream
PushbackInputStream pbBufferedIn = new PushbackInputStream(bufferedIn, 20);
boolean markDone = false; // Flag for mark
boolean resetDone = false; // Flag for reset

// Read each byte in the stream (some twice)
for (int i = pbBufferedIn.read(); i != -1; i = pbBufferedIn.read()) {
    // Convert to byte
    byte b = (byte) i;
    // Check for marking before value -1
    if (!markDone) {
        if (b == -1) {
            // Push character back
            pbBufferedIn.unread(i);
            // Mark for later rewind
            pbBufferedIn.mark(20);
            markDone = true;
            System.out.print("[mark] ");                    
            // Re-read
            pbBufferedIn.read();
        }
    }

    // Print the current byte
    System.out.print(b + " ");

    // Check for rewind after value 1
    if (markDone && !resetDone && b == 1) {
        pbBufferedIn.reset(); // <------ mark/reset not supported!
        resetDone = true;
        System.out.print("[reset] ");
    }
}
```

Ironically `PushbackInputStream` doesn't support mark/reset... on the other hand `BufferedInputStream` that supports mark/reset don't have a push-back mechanism... How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BufferedInputStream` ( stream replay ):

- you **mark now** (start creating a buffer) so that you **can replay later** (at some buffer position).
- Also you **cannot replace the buffered** content with something else.

`PushbackInputStream` ( stream corrected-replay ):

- there is **always a buffer available** to which you can reset (at some buffer position)
- You can **provide the replay contents** to that buffer.

Below I provide the corresponding examples with length-1-buffers for simplicity:

```java
PushbackInputStream pbis = 
new PushbackInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{'a','b','c'}));
System.out.println((char)pbis.read());
System.out.println((char)pbis.read());
pbis.unread('x'); //pushback after read
System.out.println((char)pbis.read());        
System.out.println((char)pbis.read());        

BufferedInputStream bis = 
new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{'a','b','c'}));
System.out.println((char)bis.read());
bis.mark(1);//mark before read
System.out.println((char)bis.read());
bis.reset();//reset after read
System.out.println((char)bis.read());        
System.out.println((char)bis.read());
```

**Result:**

```
a
b
x   //correction
c

a
b
b   //replay
c
```

Comment: 6 years later, the solution :) Tks.

Answer (score 2):

Mark/reset is sort of the equivalent to pushback. `PushbackInputStream` is for when your input stream does not support buffering. So you read, then push that back into the stream.

With `BufferedInputStream` you just `mark(10)`, read the 10 bytes with `read(10)` then call `reset()`. Now your stream is back 10 bytes and you can read it again, so you have effectively picked at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mark and reset you don't need pushback as well.

Comment: I'm interested in your solution without pushback, if you have one.